# Javascript Insert Another Parameter into Function

Tags: javascript

I would like to insert another parameter into my javascript onclick function.

Original:

```
onclick="javascript:getClickURL(\'{0}\')
```

Modified:

```
onclick="javascript:getClickURL(\'{0},{1}\')
```

However, the output is being displayed as a whole string instead of 2 variables declared. {0} has both the values, and {1} is undefined.

May I know how can I change it such that it will be assigned to 2 seperate variables instead of combining them with 1?

Thank you.

Comment: `onclick="javascript:getClickURL(\'{0}\',\'{1}\')` I think is what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to escape quote in dobule quotes:

Insted:

```
onclick="javascript:getClickURL(\'{0},{1}\')"
```

use:

```
onclick="javascript:getClickURL('{0}','{1}')"
```